# Can I get content to appear in the middle column of a CSS Grid layout with only one div?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

If I have a 3 column grid and I want the content to appear in the 2 column: am I understanding correctly that the content HAS to go in the 2nd column in the HTML, and I have to create an empty div in the HTML?

In the grid below I want the title to appear in the middle column so I've created an empty div before this.

There's no way of getting the title to appear in the middle one of the 3 columns whilst only using one div is there?

** Note I haven't included a div for the 3rd column because I don't need to.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/rEoKPg

Code snippet also included below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row {
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.grid {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="grid grid-item-1"></div>
  <div class="grid grid-item-2">The Title</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use flex? Then it can be centered nicely with `justify-content: center;` like you did on `body` in your CodePen.

Comment: I think you have an [XY Problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if all you want is a single column of content, centered on the page, CSS grid is probably not the way to go. You have one element, center that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to create an empty div if you use [`grid-column-start`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-start), but you will need to specify the column number.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="grid grid-item-2">The Title</div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row {
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.grid {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.grid-item-2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Remove the first div then add this to your css code:

```css
.grid-item-2 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}
```

Check this article on CSS Tricks with a quick cheatsheet on CSS Grids: [A Complete Guide to Grid | CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

The MDN reference is very good also: [CSS Grid Layout | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

Comment: This answer could be improved by putting your code in the context of the original question.